# In Magento how to get JSONP data using REST calls

Tags: magento, magento-1.4, magento-1.7, magento-1.5

I am new to the magento. I have installed everything and I have modified the REST roles and attributes for customer and guest. Now I am receiving the data when i give my url like *http://192.168.1.101:8010/magento/api/rest/products* in XML format.

To receive this in JSONP format I read that we have to include header like header ('Content-Type: application/javascript'); .. BUt in which file we have to include this header and where are those files located??? I dont know correctly but I think we have to include this header in api's of magento.. where are those located???

Please help me.. because time is running out..

Answer (score 2):

Please add header as follow Content-Type:application/json for JSON .

Comment: hey I dont know in which file i have to add this header.. I am getting XML output simply by running the url  http://192.168.1.101:8010/magento/api/rest/products not more than that..But in which file in have to add this header??

Comment: please use REST Clients add-on for Firefox for testing REST API in magento

Comment: But using the add-on it can be for viewing only.. But now i have to send the data to html pages in json format.. u said we have to include header of content-type... in which file we have to include this header???

Comment: i need to chat with you some time to clear my doubts about magento... can u invite me to chat?

Comment: is there any room for magento.. I cant see it

Comment: Sorry i was able to come because i was working for a client I have added you in fb

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21551/discussion-between-pavankumar-and-chanz)